# R: ggplot2 plot hourly data faceted by weekday

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot data hourly. I've search all the questions related to this topic, without success.

Most of them tell to transform to `POSIXct` format. I've made that but the `x axis` shows months not hours.

This is the str() for the data frame:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   685 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ dias  : chr  "dom" "dom" "dom" "dom" ...
 $ horas : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-03 13:45:53" ...
 $ conteo: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
  ..$ cols   :List of 3
  .. ..$ dias  : list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
  .. ..$ horas :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ format: chr ""
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_datetime" "collector"
  .. ..$ conteo: list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
  ..$ default: list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

I would also like to facet this graph by weekday. I've made this drawing to make my point:

[image]

I've made this:

[image]

With this code:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=horas, y=conteo)) +
  #geom_point() +
  geom_bar(colour = "blue",stat = "identity") +
  #facet_wrap(~ dias) +
  ylab("Sismos") + 
  xlab("Hora") +
  #opts(title = "Precipitacion acumulada horaria \n 2008-05-27 Burriana") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2))
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(dias = c("dom", "dom", "dom", "dom", "dom", "dom", 
                          "dom", "dom", "dom", "jue", "jue", "jue", "jue", "jue", "jue", 
                          "jue", "jue", "jue", "jue", "lun", "lun", "lun", "lun", "lun", 
                          "lun", "lun", "lun", "lun", "lun", "mar", "mar", "mar", "mar", 
                          "mar", "mar", "mar", "mar", "mar", "mar", "mar", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", 
                          "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", 
                          "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "mi<e9>", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", 
                          "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", 
                          "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "s<e1>b", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", 
                          "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie", "vie"), horas = c("03/01/2016 13:45", 
                                                                                             "10/01/2016 03:57", "10/01/2016 08:22", "10/01/2016 15:43", "18/09/2016 07:05", 
                                                                                             "18/09/2016 12:37", "25/09/2016 00:09", "25/09/2016 07:10", "25/09/2016 11:02", 
                                                                                             "31/12/2015 21:26", "31/12/2015 23:18", "07/01/2016 09:55", "07/01/2016 21:17", 
                                                                                             "07/01/2016 22:14", "14/01/2016 01:05", "14/01/2016 02:35", "14/01/2016 12:43", 
                                                                                             "14/01/2016 13:30", "21/01/2016 06:44", "04/01/2016 11:36", "04/01/2016 14:01", 
                                                                                             "04/01/2016 20:51", "04/01/2016 21:25", "04/01/2016 22:53", "11/01/2016 04:58", 
                                                                                             "11/01/2016 17:23", "18/01/2016 20:11", "18/01/2016 21:04", "18/01/2016 22:28", 
                                                                                             "05/01/2016 00:14", "05/01/2016 01:23", "05/01/2016 03:22", "05/01/2016 04:45", 
                                                                                             "05/01/2016 21:00", "05/01/2016 21:13", "12/01/2016 06:50", "12/01/2016 14:12", 
                                                                                             "19/01/2016 00:45", "19/01/2016 03:28", "19/01/2016 07:52", "13/01/2016 02:09", 
                                                                                             "13/01/2016 02:30", "13/01/2016 02:52", "13/01/2016 03:22", "13/01/2016 04:02", 
                                                                                             "13/01/2016 05:41", "13/01/2016 07:20", "13/01/2016 08:45", "13/01/2016 15:05", 
                                                                                             "20/01/2016 07:01", "20/01/2016 18:20", "27/01/2016 00:49", "09/01/2016 21:19", 
                                                                                             "09/01/2016 22:29", "16/01/2016 00:25", "16/01/2016 05:28", "16/01/2016 05:59", 
                                                                                             "16/01/2016 16:39", "23/01/2016 02:31", "23/01/2016 03:46", "23/01/2016 19:51", 
                                                                                             "30/01/2016 08:04", "30/01/2016 11:03", "30/01/2016 14:55", "06/02/2016 01:20", 
                                                                                             "20/02/2016 22:51", "22/01/2016 04:19", "22/01/2016 14:11", "29/01/2016 03:41", 
                                                                                             "29/01/2016 11:06", "29/01/2016 11:37", "29/01/2016 12:27", "05/02/2016 12:44", 
                                                                                             "12/02/2016 01:50", "12/02/2016 08:11", "12/02/2016 22:46", "12/02/2016 23:32", 
                                                                                             "19/02/2016 11:27", "19/02/2016 18:27"), conteo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -79L), .Names = c("dias", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "horas", "conteo"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         dias = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector")), horas = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), conteo = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "collector"))), .Names = c("dias", "horas", "conteo")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I would recommend drawing out the weekday with `lubridate` then using `facet_wrap(~weekday)`

Comment: The problem with `lubridate` is that returns the weekdays in english. The base function `weekdays` returns in local language (eg. spanish for me).

Comment: The range of `dias` is `"2015-12-31 21:26:00" "2016-09-25 11:02:00"` (it gets translated to my local time). That range == you'll see months on the axis. What exactly are you trying to plot?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I don't mind the month part, just the `time`. Need to plot hourly `conteo` faceted by weekday. In `dias` u see that range because of `data$horas <- as.POSIXct(data$fecha_hora, format="%H:%M:%S")` returns not only the hour but also the date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the calculations outside of ggplot2 as well. This can be formatted better but it depends on the version of ggplot2 you are using (and from where). This also orders the days:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# `data` is a super-bad name for a variable so I used `df` which is
# only marginally better. ideally, you'd use something far more 
# descriptive so your future self doesn't hate you.

mutate(df, dias=ifelse(dias=="mi<e9>", "mie", dias)) %>%       # needed to do this on my system with your `dput()`
  mutate(dias=ifelse(dias=="s<e1>b", "sab", dias)) %>%         # needed to do this on my system with your `dput()`
  mutate(dias=factor(dias, levels=c("lun", "mar", "mie", "jue", "vie", "sab", "dom"))) %>%  # ordered days; i'd personally start them on Sunday but I have no idea what you need
  mutate(horas=as.POSIXct(horas, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
  mutate(hour=lubridate::hour(horas)) -> df

count(df, dias, hour, wt=conteo) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour, n)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=hour, yend=0)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0, 12, 23),
                     labels=c("00:00", "12:00", "23:00"),
                     limits=c(0,23)) +
  facet_wrap(~dias, scales="free_x") +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0, face="bold")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=c(0, 0.5, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially for the beautiful resulting graph. At first I thought you've used your  `geom_lollipop` (which is very nice), but actually u used `geom_segment` + `geom_point`. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

I think (like the other comments) if you go about extracting the day of the week and the time of day as separate columns, it will make your plotting life a little clearer:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data %<>% mutate(horas = dmy_hm(horas)) # convert to a time class
data %<>% mutate(reloj = hour(horas) + minute(horas)/60) # seperate time of day
data %<>% mutate(dias = wday(horas, label = T)) # seperate day of week

ggplot(data=data,aes(x=reloj)) +
    geom_histogram(colour = "blue",bins = 20) + # change from geom_bar (drop y aesthetic)
    facet_wrap(~ dias) +
    ylab("Sismos") + 
    xlab("Hora")
```

[image]

You can adjust the number assigned to `bins = ...` to adjust the size of the "bins" that `geom_histogram` is using for bucketing and counting, perhaps reduce the number to get closer to your paper sketch.

Comment: Yes, but in the `x axi` would need this format: "00:00" for the time. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. the main problem was I was using the `geom_bar` instead of `geom_histogram`. Now I'm trying with `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%H:%M:%S"))` but got: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`. I'll keep looking.